# Django NameError - Name 's' is not defined

Tags: python, ajax, django, list, view

Amateur Developer,
I have the following code that worked fine in Python 2.7, Django 1.10. But now as I upgraded to Django 2+ and Python 3+ it gives an error.

**View code:**

```
def get_class_name(request):
    class_name = ClassName.objects.get(pk = request.GET.get('class_name', None))
    classes = Class.objects.filter(class_name = class_name)
    l = [[", ".join([s.subject for s in x.subject.all()]),s.id] for x in classes]
```

**The error message:**
NameError at /ajax/get_class_name/
name 's' is not defined
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/ajax/get_class_name/?class_name=1
Django Version: 2.0
Exception Type: NameError
Exception Value:
name 's' is not defined

**Model:**
    class Class(models.Model):
        subject = models.ManyToManyField(Subject)

How do I fix it?

Comment: The problem is in this line: "l = [[", ".join ([s.subject for s in x.subject.all ()]), s.id] for x in classes]" because when you try to build the Second list, you use the variable "s" out of context, because "s" only exists within the creation of the second list. What do you want to do in this line?

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_class_name(request, pk):
    pk = request.GET.get('class_name', None)
    class_name = ClassName.objects.get(pk = pk)
    classes = Class.objects.filter(class_name = class_name)
    l = [[", ".join([s.subject for s in x.subject.all()]),s.id] for x in classes]
```

Comment: Have u passed pk in arguments?

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_class_name(request):
    class_name = ClassName.objects.get(pk = request.GET.get('class_name', None))
    classes = Class.objects.filter(class_name = class_name)
    l = [[", ".join([s.subject for s in x.subject.all()]),x.id] for x in classes]
```

I think the problem is at `,s.id] for x` s is outside of the first list comprehension, may be you meant `,x.id] for x in classes]` ?

Comment: Yes the error is happening at the s.id as you said, I now recognize. Hopefully I will soon get it out.